# Need to install just libswresample.so.0 on Centos 6 - how? (for FFMPEG)

Tags: linux, centos, configuration, ffmpeg, libraries

I'm trying to get ffmpeg running on a Centos 6 machine and it has been uphill the whole way. I thought I had got it but when I go to use ffmpeg I get the error:

```
ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libswresample.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I looked in /usr/local/lib, which is where all the libraries are stored, and I do not have that exact file but I do have "libswresample.a". I gave up on the official FFMPEG Centos directions due to all kinds of issues and used yum to install.

Where do I find the missing library and can I just put the file in my /usr/local/lib to fix?

Thanks -- have a basic Linux understanding, more familiar with Ubuntu than Centos.

Comment: have you installed the appropriate package to provide this library?

Comment: I'm not sure - I installed libtheora, libvorbis, x264, libogg, ffmpeg-devel. Have tried removing and reinstalling each and I can't seem to find out which includes libswresample. It would seem that FFMPEG is supposed to provide it from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651816/libswresample-in-recent-ubuntu-version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [quick search](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libswresample.so&submit=Search%20...) at RPMFIND.net yields `ffmpeg-devel`.

HTH

Comment: Thanks! I must have uninstalled, I put it back on and this got me past libswresample -- onto the next problem :)

Answer (score 0):

this may help..

https://github.com/supermasita/ufe/wiki/Installing-FFMPEG-on-CentOS-with-ATRPMS-repo

1. rpm --import http://packages.atrpms.net/RPM-GPG-KEY.atrpms
2. vim /etc/yum.repos.d/atrpms.repo

Comment: Although you list the actions they are incomplete by themselves (what to put in the `atrpms.repo` file for instance?) and also please provide the rationale for your steps in your answer instead of just a link. ServerFault is better with [complete answers](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!